# SUMIFS Issue on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula, sumifs

I'm using the following formula to pull in data from the Purchases sheet tab on Google Sheets within our spreadsheet.

=SUMIFS(PURCHASES!$H$2:$H$2000,PURCHASES!$F$2:$F$2000,"101")

What's happening though is every entry is causing the "2" and the "2000" to increase by 1. I don't want that, because data could then be missed (and it is).  Any ideas?

I really need help. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet that has the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

We cannot know exactly what is going on, because we can't see your sheet. But two common ways to fix the issue are these:

1.) Use INDIRECT for your references:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("PURCHASES!H2:H2000"),INDIRECT("PURCHASES!F2:F2000"),"101")
```

2.) Include the entire column as the reference:

```
=SUMIFS(PURCHASES!$H:$H,PURCHASES!$F:$F,"101")
```

There are other options as well, but they'd require our being able to view your sheet via a shared link.